# Can't access fetch post data in controller: Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, fetch

I'm making a post request using fetch in my codeigniter project. The request looks like this

```
fetch('myurl/mycontroller', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
         testdata: 123,
    })
 }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
 }).catch(console.log);
```

My controller looks like below

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller
{
    public function mycontroller()
    {
        $data = $this->input->post('testdata');
        return $data . " is the passed data.";
    }
}
```

But the data isn't getting passed to my controller. I echoed out `$_POST` and it gave me an empty array. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm using codeigniter 2 (which I know is very old now)

Comment: Can you post your entire controller?

Comment: this is my entire controller. I just started the test and I couldn't get the data to post

Comment: I haven't used codeigniter 2 in a long time. But I'm pretty sure the controller should be a class and not just a function.

Comment: oh I see what you mean but this is a function in the controller

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem here is codeigniter-2 or your javascript. When you use that same javascript to post to an new php file that only has the print_r($_POST) does that get anything?

Comment: just an empty array

Comment: Then the problem is not codeigniter 2 but the data being submited.

Comment: thanks for the help but it looks like it might be a problem with codeigniter. After a lot of searching the internet I found an article that said its because the CI core of codeigniter has issues that doesn't parse the data passed properly.
I was able to pass the data usign axios and FormData. I might have misunderstood but the solution worked

Comment: If you were getting the same exact result with a simple PHP file how can that be codeigniter problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So not completely sure about the actual reason but there might be some bug with the CI core of codeigniter which doesn't parse the data passed to controller using fetch. Using `FormData()` and `axios` I was able to resolve the issue.

```
 var postData = new FormData();
 postData.append('testdata', 123);
 axios.post('myurl/mycontroller', postData).then(function(response){
     console.log("success:", response);
 }).catch(function(error){
     console.log("error:", error);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```js
let postData = new FormData();
postData.append('testdata', 123);

fetch('myurl/mycontroller', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: postData
 }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
 }).catch(console.log);
```

Use `formData` and `mode: 'no-cors'` in fetch settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me what version of Codeigniter you are using? The one I was working on was Codeigniter 2 (I know an outdated version) but for Codeigniter 2, it can't properly format the post data for the back end to read it properly. Adding the mode made no difference.

Comment: hi @JustinS, i am currently using CI v3.1.11. In the controller I use `$this->input->post()` to receive the data. The version could be the difference.

Comment: This combination is the one that worked for me after hours of head scratching! Funny enough I use CI 3.1 all the time but this is a plain PHP script. So two for one!

Answer (score 1):

Use `FormData()` to submit it

```
var postData = new FormData();
postData.append('testdata', 123);

fetch('myurl/mycontroller', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: postData
 }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
 }).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: I tried this solution and got the same result. No data is getting passed. echoing $_POST is still an empty array

Comment: try this on the controller `$input = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true); $data = $input['testdata']` and use your fetch

Comment: i was able to solve this using axios instead of fetch

Comment: @justinS can you please post the solution so that someone might find it later?

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue, i later fixed it without changing away from js fetch.
Here is how i resolved it.

- Make sure you have a Post route in your routing file to your CI controller
- Make sure your fetch api url has no trailing '/'

```
let data = await fetch('https://example.com/api/login', {
              method: 'POST',
              credentials: 'same-origin',
              mode: 'same-origin',
              headers: {
                'Accept':       'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',

              },
              body: JSON.stringify({email: 'sample@gmail.com', password: 'crypt887faked'}),
          });

          let response = await data.json();
```

This worked for me. I hope it works for someone also.